# Is it possible within Backbone.js to reload route with history.loadUrl and pass in a string to be used as success message?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having trouble working out if it is possible to pass a string into a view using backgone.history.loadUrl?

```
//My current method of reloading the view    
Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);
```

I would like to use this method if possible so that it renders the view from the Backbone router rather then rendering my view again from within itself and passing it in as the options for that view.

```
//Destroy old view
//Render view again    
var view = new myView("success msg");
```

Comment: [Possible XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): It's not clear what you want to do - what passes the message to `loadUrl()`? Where does it come from? What was the intention behind the `loadUrl()` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to extend `Backbone.history` with a reload function:

```
_.extend(Backbone.history, {
    reload: function(){
        return this.loadUrl(this.getFragment());
    }
});
```

<sup>*Don't do this if you're writing a library/plugin.*</sup>

Then calling `Backbone.history.reload();` anywhere will call the route again.

Is it a good way to re-render a view? **No.**

If you want to re-render a view within itself, do that, don't reload the whole route.

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    // events, etc. ...
    render: function() {
        // rendering
        if (this.success) {
            // show success message
        }
        return this;
    },
    onMyEvent: function() {
        // here, a re-render with a success message is necessary
        this.success = true;
        this.render();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank's Emile, this makes sense. I was over complicating things.